# Tabulate checkboxes within different checkbars - Tkinter

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter, label

I am doing a GUI with Tkinter and I am trying to show the checkboxes from two checkbars tabulated. I tried (as you can see in the code) to check if the problem was that the labels were not the same length, but after adding some blank spaces when needed; it seems this was not the problem. Any ideas why this could be happenning?

```
class Checkbar(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, picks={}, side=LEFT, anchor=W, list_keys=[]):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.vars = []

        for key, value in picks.items():
            var = IntVar()
            chk = Checkbutton(self, text=self.SameLength(list_keys, key), variable=var)
            button_ttp = ToolTip(chk, value)
            chk.pack(side=side, anchor=anchor, expand=YES, )

    def SameLength(self, listStrings, word):
        return word.ljust(len(max(listStrings, key=len)), '0')
```

[image]

As you can see in the image, the checkboxes are note well tabulated and do not know why is this happening as the labels have all the same length.

I also have tried to use grid instead of pack, but still does not work.
[using grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7FAB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than padding the checkbuttons' text with spaces (which doesn't work because all characters don't have the same length) you can set the checkbuttons' width (in characters):

```
Checkbutton(.., width=maxwidth, anchor='w', ...)
```

where `maxwidth = len(max(list_keys, key=len))`. You also need to set the `anchor` option to `'w'` to align the checkboxes to the left.

This is the full code I used to test my answer:

```
from tkinter import *

class Checkbar(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, picks={}, side=LEFT, anchor=W, list_keys=[]):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.vars = []
        maxwidth = len(max(list_keys, key=len))

        for key, value in picks.items():
            var = IntVar()
            chk = Checkbutton(self, text=key, variable=var, width=maxwidth, anchor='w')
            # button_ttp = ToolTip(chk, value)
            chk.pack(side=side, anchor=anchor, expand=YES, )



root = Tk()
list_keys = ['1', '2', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight']

Label(root, text='Select keyword(s):').grid(row=0, column=0)
Checkbar(root, picks={k: k for k in list_keys[:4]}, list_keys=list_keys).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='w')
Checkbar(root, picks={k: k for k in list_keys[4:]}, list_keys=list_keys).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')
root.mainloop()
```

which gives:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer but after trying it I´m still facing the same problem..

Comment: @EpicaSjH I edited my answer to add the full code snippet I used and a screenshot of the result. As you can see, the checkboxes are aligned. The code in the question doesn't show how you put the `Checkbar` in the GUI so I don't know if the problem comes from there.

Comment: Thank you so much! It finally works! I did not realize that I just forgot to add the anchor parameter in the checkbutton... I was only changing it in "chk.pack". Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to lay widgets out in a grid, tkinter has a geometry manager optimized to do just that: `grid`. Using `grid` is preferable over `pack` in this case since it allows you to lay out widgets in rows and columns.

Comment: Hi, I just modified it (instead of pack using grid). However, it keeps doing the same...                                                 
[...]  chk.grid(column=col, row=numrow, sticky=W+E)
       col = col+1